# Showing different legends for each bar in RadCharts with nativescript angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, radchart

am trying to have different legends labels with their own colors representing each column in the bar series. As you see in the screen shot, i can't get other legends to appear.
[image]

Also each should have a different color. Here is my html.

```
            <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis allowPan="true" allowZoom="true"></CategoricalAxis>
            <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis allowPan="true"></LinearAxis>

            <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="LivestockData"
                categoryProperty="Year" valueProperty="Amount" seriesName="Bar" showLabels="true" legendTitle="Cattle"></BarSeries>

            <!-- >> chart-legend-angular-definition -->                   
            <RadLegendView tkCartesianLegend position="Bottom" title="Species"
                height="150" enableSelection="true"></RadLegendView>                    

            <!-- << chart-angular-styling-bars -->
            <Palette tkCartesianPalette seriesName="Bar">
                <PaletteEntry tkCartesianPaletteEntry fillColor="#A05BC5"></PaletteEntry>
            </Palette>

        </RadCartesianChart>
```

Here is the data am showing.

```
    { species: "Cattle", Amount: 4771, Year: 1980 },
    { species: "Sheep and goats", Amount: 3862, Year: 2000 },
    { species: "Pigs", Amount: 187, Year: 2002 },
    { species: "Poultry", Amount: 2941, Year: 1990 }
```

The species property values should be in the legends but i can only show cattle value and i also need different colors for each. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground? https://play.nativescript.org

Comment: Okay let me do that

Comment: Here is the link to the sample i have created. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WUcdqL&v=2

Answer (score 0):

I have the playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WUcdqL&v=3). To have the mutiple colors for the Bars, you need to comment out the `Palette` section and add the `paletteMode="Item"` in your Bar Series.

```
<BarSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="categoricalSource"
            categoryProperty="Year" paletteMode="Item" valueProperty="Amount"
            seriesName="Bar" legendTitle="Cattle" showLabels="true"></BarSeries>
```

Also Legend is working fine as they represents series type and you can modity the legendTitle per series. If you want multiple legends, you need to add mutiple Bar series(for each cattle in your case.)

Comment: Thanks for the paletteMode="Item" solution. It works great. So can each color be made to appear on the legendTitle representing the species values. Since i have cattle,Sheep and goats, Pigs, Poultry. Is there a way to bind the legendTitle to the species values such that i have all appear instead of only cattle.

Comment: legend represents series type and you can modity the legendTitle per series. So if you want  cattle,Sheep and goats, Pigs, Poultry as legend, you may need 4 Bar series.

Comment: That's really tricky with dynamic data since that is what am going to be dealing with. I will give it a try and respond. Thanks

Comment: I think what i was looking for was the legendLabel property, unfortunately it seems to work only on piecharts. Here is the playground demo i made. [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WUcdqL&v=6)